# I want to add one more dynamic row after user clicking on button using Angular 6 and typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I want to add one more row using Angular 6 and typescript.
I am using Angular 6 and typescript.
My code looks like this:
Medicine NameDosageNone{{frequency.value}}AdviceDuration+ Add

Comment: Can You rephrase Your question In a more elaborative manner

Comment: @Benson OO i want to add more row when click on add button (typescript, angular 6 code)

Comment: Please edit your original post explaining what your desired end goal is.

Comment: as far as i understood your question,you want to dynamically add a <mat-option> option on button click.By the way follow the guidelines here to refactor your code,its difficult to understand

Comment: Actually I want to add a dynamic row when user will click on add button you can see image which I have upload here

Answer (score 0):

what you do in your template (you shared with us) is a traversing through frequencys variable defined somewhere in your ts file. So you need to add button, which adds record to this frequencys array.

add to template:

```
<button (click)="addRecord()">add</button>
```

you need to add said addRecord method to your ts file

```
...
addRecord() {
 this.frequencys.push("test");
}
```

This will add "test" field into your list. If you want user to be able to set title, you need to add `<input>` tag to your template and (for example via ngModel) get input value (and push it into frequencys, instead of "test").
Cheers

Comment: I add this code in oninit()                                                                   
 addRecord() {
 this.frequencys.push("test");
} but it is showing error plz guide

Comment: @Anusha Please rewrite/update the question properly. Like, what you are doing and what you want to achieve and what is not working as you expected?

Comment: ngOnInit() { ... }
addRecord() { ... }